# Best way to improve Twilio client identifiers

Tags: twilio

Today when I receive a call, I get:

```
{"call_state":"PENDING","call_to":"client:test123","call_from":"client:test321","call_sid":"CA45af5dadsad3e699b9cb8d9"}
```

To not display **test123**, at the moment that I receive the event I search in my database the specific ID (123) and then I give to the user the right name.

That said, I would like to know if there's another way to add more information at the Client Identifiers avoiding the database search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't add more information in that request, however you could make your Client ID more useful.

You want your client identifier to be unique, and I assume the names you want to display aren't necessarily. So, if you make the client identifier something like "#{id}-#{username}" it will be unique as it contains the ID, but you could split the string on "-" and use the username to display to your user.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that one of you guys to answer the question. I'm already splitting the client identifier and since you had confirm that I'll continue the way it is.